# Подсчёт суммы, в уникальных наборах данных (Java)

Tags: java, массивы

Имеется массив:

```
[
  [Вася, повар, 3года, 300],
  [Вася, повар, 3года, 500],
  [Петя, повар, 4года, 100],
  [Вася, повар, 3года, 800],
  [Петя, повар, 4года, 300] 
  ... n
]
```

Необходимо просуммировать последний элемент списка для каждого уникального набора данных. В данном случае для `[Вася, повар, 3года]` это `1600`, а для `[Петя, повар, 4года]` это `400`.
Помогите пожалуйста реализовать задачу.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы сделал это как-то так (oсновная идея - считаем хэшкод объекта `Person` без учета `value`):

```
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
    /*
        Заполняем массив
     */
    Map<Integer, Integer> sumMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for(Person person : persons){
        if(sumMap.containsKey(person.hashCode())){
            sumMap.put(person.hashCode(), sumMap.get(person.hashCode()) + person.value);
        } else {
            sumMap.put(person.hashCode(), person.value);
        }
    }
```

Класс `Person`:

```
class Person {

    Person(String name, String position, String age, int value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.position = position;
        this.age = age;
        this.value = value;
    }

    String name;
    String position;
    String age;
    int value;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Person person = (Person) o;

        if (value != person.value) return false;
        if (age != null ? !age.equals(person.age) : person.age != null) return false;
        if (name != null ? !name.equals(person.name) : person.name != null) return false;
        if (position != null ? !position.equals(person.position) : person.position != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (position != null ? position.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (age != null ? age.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Хороший способ) но к сожалению в системе, в которой работаю, нет возможности создавать свои классы, я могу только использовать стандартные классы Java

Comment: В таком случае как выглядит ваш массив? У вас двумерный массив строк получается? В таком случае такой способ тоже применим.

Comment: да, двумерный, размерностью например [n][7], где седьмой элемент это число которое нужно суммировать, а как тогда код преобразуется без классов и оверайдов? был бы по опытней, не создавал бы вопрос)) спасибо что отвечаете

Comment: Ну хэшкод считается в моем примере от полей, вы его можете аналогично считать от элементов массива.

Answer (score 1):

Если совсем дедовскими методами тогда так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[][] arr = {
            {"Вася", "повар", "3года", "300"},
            {"Вася", "повар", "3года", "500"},
            {"Петя", "повар", "4года", "100"},
            {"Вася", "повар", "3года", "800"},
            {"Петя", "повар", "4года", "300"}
    };

    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        String key = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i][j] + "\t");
            key += arr[i][j]+" ";
        }
        Integer val = Integer.valueOf(arr[i][3]);

        System.out.print("Key :"+key);
        System.out.print("Val :"+val);

        Integer sum = map.get(key);
        sum = (sum==null) ? val : sum + val;
        map.put(key,sum);

        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println(map);

}
```

Результат

```
    Вася    повар   3года   Key :Вася повар 3года Val :300
    Вася    повар   3года   Key :Вася повар 3года Val :500
    Петя    повар   4года   Key :Петя повар 4года Val :100
    Вася    повар   3года   Key :Вася повар 3года Val :800
    Петя    повар   4года   Key :Петя повар 4года Val :300

    {Петя повар 4года =400, Вася повар 3года =1600}

    Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Класс был, склейка полей ключа в строку была, добавлю еще злоупотребление списком в качестве ключа (ну и стримы):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] records = {
            {"Вася", "повар", "3года", "300"},
            {"Вася", "повар", "3года", "500"},
            {"Петя", "повар", "4года", "100"},
            {"Вася", "повар", "3года", "800"},
            {"Петя", "повар", "4года", "300"}
        };

    Arrays.stream( records ).collect( 
            Collectors.groupingBy( 
                    record -> Arrays.asList( record ).subList(0, 3), 
                    Collectors.reducing( 
                            0, 
                            record -> Integer.valueOf( record[3] ),
                            Integer::sum
                        )
                )
        ).entrySet().forEach( System.out::println );
}
```